# Image gets scale on every touch end after drawing on it - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, touches

I am using this *raywenderlich tutorial* for the drawing on Image. That tutorial is with no image in background but here I want to draw on image from gallery.

So basically there are two `UIImageView` one is `mainImage` and `tempDrawImage`. 
I am doing `self.mainImage.image = randomImageFromGallery` as a background image on which I want to draw
Now it shows up well n drawing also happens but the problem is image gets scale on every touch end.

Why the image keeps on scaling whats wrong with the code I am not doing anything on `tempDrawImage` where all the drawing happens ?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    lastPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    mouseSwiped = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    CGContextRef ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    CGContextSetLineCap(ctxt, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, brush );
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctxt, red, green, blue, 1.0);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(ctxt,kCGBlendModeNormal);

    CGContextStrokePath(ctxt);
    self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];

    lastPoint = currentPoint;
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if(!mouseSwiped)
    {
        self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if(!mouseSwiped) {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, opacity);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), lastPoint.x, lastPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.mainImage.frame.size);
    [self.mainImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
    [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
    self.mainImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    self.tempDrawImage.image = nil;
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Comment: What are the frames of each of the views?

Comment: @Wain : There are two UIImageView as I said in the queston first is mainImage width: 316 & height is 563 and tempDrawImage is 316 x 563 same .. where's the original view on which UIImages are added is 320 x 568 which comes by default with the viewcontroller

Comment: @Wain : Got the hint out of it ...Thanks..it's working now the problem was the size of both the frames were different so it will scale according to the local co-ordinates ..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the size of the frames of all of the views you're using. Somewhere there is a mismatch so that one of the images your displaying is being scaled for display. Either the size the image is drawn at or the size it's displayed at needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you have a picture, and you want to draw up to this picture...

I propose :

1. set your tempDrawImage as inherited from UIView instead of UIImageView.
2. Store the points in an array while touches actions (touchesBegan, touchesMoved,...)
3. draw in the procedure (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect